# Data lost when exception occurs in inserting data

Tags: python, database, python-2.7, sybase

Suppose I am having 50 records which I want to insert in database. I am calling commit method at the end of execution of 50th record (bulk insert). While inserting the 45th record, I'm getting some exception and I'm catching that exception. But when I see the data in the database, it only shows me data from 46th to 50th. All other data before 45th is not inserted into the database because I got an error at the 45th record. How can we solve this issue?

```py
def insert_data(self, query):
   cursor = database.cursor()
   try:
      cursor.execute(query)
    except Exception:
       print("Exception")
    else:
       cursor.close()

def process(self):
  database = DB.conn() // Get connection
  for x in range(50):
     self.insert_data("insert.......")
 database.commit()// commit after for ends
```

Comment: Try using `try/except/finally` construct

Comment: So do I have to commit the data for every insert?

Comment: No, I meant changing `else: cursor.close()` to `finally: cursor.close()` so that it runs regardless of what happened.

Comment: Does the query involve multiple operations?

Comment: Hi @Knot and welcome to SO! Please try to be more specific with your question and/or example - as right now we don't see your bulk operation or your insert at all.

Comment: @abdusco please check update question

Comment: You should let the exception bubble up to `process` (use `raise` after printing/logging), add a `finally` clause in `process` and commit there

Comment: Which Sybase product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and what are the details of the error/exception? without more details I'm **guessing** this is what happened: `begin tran`, `insert rows 1-45`, `deadlock` occurs at row #45 which causes a `rollback tran` which in turn undoes inserts #1-45, then your code (effectively) ignores the `deadlock/rollback` and continues to `insert rows 46-50`; net result, database only contains rows 46-50